# How do you prevent a grid item from overflowing the grid?

Tags: css

I'm using the following to create a grid that scales from three columns to two, then one on mobile:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill(minmax(400px,1fr));
```

It works fine, except on mobile devices the min setting causes each item to overflow the grid container (and screen).

Is there any other way I can write the columns to prevent this?

i.e. "Minimum 400px, except if it overflows the parent container"

Comment: Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/folosophy/rxaon7kw. As you can see, when you resize the window to less than 480px it just chops off the grid item, instead of scaling it down. You can use max-width, as this gets ignored by display:grid.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `400px` with `min(400px, 100%)`. That basically does as you ask, sets the minimum value to 400px unless it overflows, then it is 100%.

Though beware browser support for `min`: https://caniuse.com/?search=min()

Best practice is to put in two declarations:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill(minmax(400px, 1fr));
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill(minmax(min(400px, 100%), 1fr));
```

And the browsers that support it will follow the second one.